# I want to create several boxes and place thumb nails in them that link to larger pics

Tags: css

I want to create several boxes and place thumb nails in them that link to larger pics is it best to use css or tables?

Answer (score 2):

This calls for CSS.  Tables are for tabular data, not layout.  Using divs styled with CSS will make the layout more flexible, easier to edit, and more accessible to both users and search engines.